# How can I interact with a facebook app page without always generating a token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making an API to post to our companys facebook page but all documentation and request errors require me to get a page access token but this is supposed to run on the server and its a bit inconvenient for our dev team to every 2 months have to generate a new token and restart the app so my question is if its possible to use the app id and secret only or get a permanent token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a couple time after posting this question here at stackoverflow that facebook has system users that allow you to generate tokens for server side services that dont need a specific user data.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/system-users

You will need to make your sys user admin to make posts and what not.